# How do I change the text of a button when it is clicked? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, text, uibutton

I'm new to programming so keep that in mind. I have looked at several other questions on this site, and tried the answers they gave, but those haven't worked for me. The code I am trying to use to change the button to is this:

```
@IBAction func AnswerButtonA(sender: UIButton)
{
    [AnswerButtonA setTitle:@"Hello World" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

This is the most common method to do this I have found but it brings up several errors "Expected declaration" "Expected attribute name" "expected ',' separator, and a few others.

Another thing I tried that others suggested is:

```
@IBAction func AnswerButtonA(sender: UIButton)
{
    AnswerButtonA.setTitle("Hello World")
}
```

This as well as a few other things I've tried all bring up the error "'(UIButton) ->()' does not have a member named 'setTitle'.

I realize this may be a stupid question but I can't figure it out. This is the first app I have tried to develop on my own and I have done fine until this problem. Any help would be appreciated, and if you could go into detail about what I'm doing wrong that would be amazing!

(I only want the button to change when it is pressed, not when the view is loaded.)

Comment: What is `AnswerButtonA` ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In your first question you're trying to use Objective-C code in a Swift file.

In your second example, you're not passing the control state.

In both instances, as Jeremy Pope points out, you're referring to `AnswerButtonA` as the method, not the button.

You need to create an outlet to your button (or use `sender` as in Jeremy's answer).

From there, here's what you're looking for:

```
answerButtonA.setTitle("Hello World", forState: .Normal)
```

The method signature will pop up as you're typing:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much!! I didn't think to distinguish swift from objective-c in the answers I was reading, I'll definitely keep that in mind in the future! This worked perfectly! Thanks!!

Comment: Great answer, both with resources and temperament.

Answer (score 4):

The button being pressed is being sent as an argument called sender.  AnswerButtonA is the method which you created.  Just a style note, usually the first letter is lowercase for methods.  So again, AnswerButtonA is the method that is called when you click the button, sender is the actual button clicked.

```
IBAction func AnswerButtonA(sender: UIButton)
{
    //sender is the button that was pressed
    sender.setTitle("HelloWorld", forState: .Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
@IBOutlet  answerButtonA : UIButton!

@IBAction func answerButtonAClicked(sender: UIButton)
{
     answerButtonA.setTitle("YourTitle", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Also read the swift style guide for learning conventions of variables names and class names. https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

Comment: If you set the action up to send the button as an argument, there isn't a need to also create an @IBOutlet for it.  Or if you are going to use the outlet, set the action to not send anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, this definitely helps you

```
@IBAction func AnswerButtonA (sender: UIButton!)
{
  sender.setTitle("Hello World", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works as well

```
(sender as AnyObject).setTitle("Un-Down", for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sender.title = "my text here"
```

for Xcode 9.3.1